# Different loggers for classes in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, logging

I have several classes in the same module - I want each to have its own class attribute of a logger from the logging module. Because of the structure of the logging module, when I add:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

each of their loggers has the same name (the module) so they are actually all the same logger. I'd prefer to have each logger to be class specific (so their names are something like package.module.ClassName). I'm aware "best practice" is generally to name your loggers **name** and also aware I could just rename them whatever I want. But I was mainly looking for what's recommended for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Consider adding contextual information required via `logging.LoggingAdapter`

## Example

```
class CustomAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
"""
This example adapter expects the passed in dict-like object to have a
'connid' key, whose value in brackets is prepended to the log message.
"""
def process(self, msg, kwargs):
    return '[%s] %s' % (self.extra['connid'], msg), kwargs

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
adapter = CustomAdapter(logger, {'connid': some_conn_id })
```

## References

Logging cookbook (search for LoggingAdapter): https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html